# Using xcode 4 to read c source

Tags: python, macos, xcode4

ALL

I want to explore python source using Xcode 4. After adding projects files to "Command Line Tool" blank project, I started reading.

But I can't found a symbols list (like functions , symbols ) bar just besides edit area like other IDE , as eclipse or pycharm ..

Is there any way to do this?

[image: like picture below]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a similar list of symbols in the current file by clicking the popup menu above the editor in Xcode (or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>). You can also filter this list by starting to type after the menu shows up.

[image: screenshot]

Xcode doesn't have a dedicated panel for this like PyCharm. There is an inspector panel for viewing *all* symbols in the current project/workspace (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>), but it can't be filtered to show only symbols in the current file.

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand panel's second tab also gives you a project-wide symbol list, which can be presented hierarchically or as a flat list. Using the bottom controls, you can further filter the symbol list.

Comment: thank u ,but i need the symbols list for current file not the whole project , for symbols is so many ...

Comment: AH! I understand - amending the answer with apologies to omz.

Comment: Good feature request would be another button on the bottom bar to show current editor's selected file's symbols, too. The jump bar requires a minimum of two mouse clicks (keyboard notwithstanding) versus a flat list of in-file symbols that remains visible. I'd use the symbol list a *lot more* were that the case.